# case types integer and character varying cannot be matched

Tags: sql, postgresql, tableau-api

```
if RAWSQL_int("jkey(app,%1,true,false)",'["providers","googleCSA","engineResponseTime"]',[app])>0 
and RAWSQL_int("jkey(app,%1,true,false)",'["providers","googleCSA","engineResponseTime"]',[app])<5000 
then RAWSQL_int("jkey(app,%1,true,false)",'["providers","googleCSA","engineResponseTime"]',[app])
else 0
end
```

Whats wrong with it? I know that if true then x else y, x y must be in same type. Mines are all integers, aren't they? int(jkey()) is a int, and 0 is also a int.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for RAW SQL statements is

```
RAWSQL_INT(“sql_expr”, [arg1], …[argN])
```

See: http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/online/mac/en-us/functions_functions_passthrough.html
so your expressions:

```
RAWSQL_int("jkey(app,%1,true,false)",'["providers","googleCSA","engineResponseTime"]',[app])
```

doesn't seem to comply with this, does it?
It has 3 parameters, the first one should be the SQL and the next ones can be arguments you can use in the SQL.

```
RAWSQL_int("jkey(app,%1,true,false)",
           '["providers","googleCSA","engineResponseTime"]',
           [app])
```

You refer to %1 in the first parameter, which would be `'["providers","googleCSA","engineResponseTime"]'` but then you don't do anything with the `[app]` part of the command.
You should probably check that.